# How exactly is ammonium sulfate formed in a Kjeldahl analysis?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

When conducting a Kjeldahl analysis,  ammonium sulfate is formed from nitrogen which protein consist of.

How in a picture of formation of ammonium sulfate there is involved no nitrogen but only some compounds containing nitrogen.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ammonia is basic so:
$$\ce{NH3 +H+<=>NH4+}$$
Sulphuric acid is acidic(since it's name is itself so acidic!):
$$\ce{H2SO4<=>H+ +HSO4- <=>2H+ +SO4^2-}$$
Now the final reaction would be like:
$$\ce{2NH3 +H2SO4<=>NH3 +NH4+ +HSO4- <=>2NH4+ +SO4^2- <=>(NH4)2SO4}$$
And remeber since proteins are polymers of peptides which itself are molecules consisiting of both a carboxylic ($\ce{-COOH/-COO-}$) and amino ($\ce{-NH3/-NH4+}$) group, therefore with strong heating ammonium sulfate is expected.